# Combining two worksheet data in a single notepad

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am new to VBA,
I have a workbook which has 3 worksheet. Sheet1 has a reference in Sheet2 and Sheet3 is independent.

I need to combine Sheet1 and Sheet3 data in a Notepad.

I can execute the script separately and its working fine but when I try to combine 2 sheet data into one notepad then it prints only the sheet3 data not with the Sheet1 data.

Below is my script.

```
Sub myself()

Dim str As String
Dim MaxStrLen As String
Dim rest As Integer
Dim Lstr As Integer
Dim LMstr As Integer
Dim MStr As Integer
Dim LR As Range
Dim CNT As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim h As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim FilePath As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

Open "C:\Users\Antony\Music\Excel Macros\Test2.txt" For Output As #2

'''''FIRST FIVE LINES WILL PRINT IN THE NOTEPAD

With ws1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        sOut = vbNullString
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            str = .Cells(i, j).Value
            MStr = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
            Lstr = Len(str)
            rest = MStr - Lstr
            sOut = sOut & str & Space(rest)
        Next
        Print #2, sOut
    Next

    '''''LAST LINE WILL PRINT IN THE SAME NOTEPAD

    ws3.Activate

    For k = 2 To LastRow
      str = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Cells(k, "A").Resize(1, LastCol).Value)), "@#")
      str = Replace(str, "=", vbNullString)

        Print #2, str
    Next


End With


Close #2

End Sub
```

Kindly help me to print both in SAME notepad; i.e., First five lines + last line

Comment: You say you want to combine the data between **Sheet1** and **Sheet3**: can you provide an example of what it should look like?

Comment: @Zac I separated with the "with statement" and combined. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've found a solution, however, there is a much better way to do this that will also ensure everything prints to the same output.

> Load up a variant with every line of data you want in your notepad and
>   then print to the output *just once*. This is **significantly** quicker than
>   printing over and over again

Here is a generic example which outputs the values in `A1:A10` in `Sheet1` and `Sheet3`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim fileNumber As Long, i As Long

    ReDim v(1 To 20)
    For i = 1 To 10
        v(i) = Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value
        v(i + 10) = Sheet3.Cells(i, "A").Value
    Next i

    fileNumber = FreeFile
    newFileName = "C:\NewTextFile.txt"

    Open newFileName For Output As #fileNumber
    Print #fileNumber, Join(v, vbCrLf)

    Close #fileNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my script which works fine 
    Sub myself()

```
Dim str As String
Dim MaxStrLen As String
Dim rest As Integer
Dim Lstr As Integer
Dim LMstr As Integer
Dim MStr As Integer
Dim LR As Range
Dim CNT As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LRow As Long
Dim LCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim h As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim FilePath As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

Open "C:\Users\Antony\Music\Excel Macros\Test.txt" For Output As #2

'''''FIRST FIVE LINES WILL PRINT IN THE NOTEPAD

With ws1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LastRow
    sOut = vbNullString
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        str = .Cells(i, j).Value
        MStr = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
        Lstr = Len(str)
        rest = MStr - Lstr
        sOut = sOut & str & Space(rest)
    Next
    Print #2, sOut
Next
End With
'''''LAST LINE WILL PRINT IN THE SAME NOTEPAD

With ws3
    LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

slast = vbNullString

For k = 2 To LRow
  str = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Cells(k, "A").Resize(1, LastCol).Value)), "@#")
  str = Replace(str, "=", vbNullString)

    Print #2, str
Next

Endtext = "EODR"

Print #2, slast & Endtext

End With


Close #2

End Sub
```